# Problem in java serial communication where values over 127 are displayed as "ef bf bd"

Tags: java, android, serial-communication

I am trying to receive and display a byte value through serial communication with another device.

```
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case UsbService.MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT:
                String data = (String) msg.obj;
                String prt = byteArrayToHex(data.getBytes());
                mActivity.get().display.append(prt);
                break;
        }
    }

    static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (final byte b : a)
        {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x ", b & 0xff));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

However, the above code has a problem that the "aa" value is changed to "ef bf bd".

Values within 127 are fine.

So, changing to String at first seems to be a problem, so if I use "byte[] data = (byte[]) msg.obj;", it crashes during execution.

How can I get the value "aa" to display properly?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `String.getBytes()`, is is going to **encode** the characters in the string using the **default** character set for your platform.  Judging from the what you are seeing, the default character set is UTF-8.

If you want characters in the range 128 to 255 to be encoded as single bytes, then you need to use a character set which maps the characters 0 - 255 to the bytes 0 - 255.  I think that LATIN-1 will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem was that the values coming from the device were in UFT-8 format when stored in msg.obj.